# LAN to LAN communication not working while internet works fine. (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, ethernet

I have 2 ethernet WLAN ports on my PC1 and 1 ethernet port PC2.

I have a small piece of code that sends and receives packets through ethernet port from PC1 to PC2(LAN to LAN communication).

**Following is the behavior I am observing:**

```
PC1 Default Ethernet port to PC2 Default ethernet port :
       LAN to LAN - OK

PC1 PCIe Half-width Ethernet port to PC2 Default ethernet port :
      LAN to LAN - **NOT Working**
```

The internet on all these 3(2 ethernet ports on PC1 and 1 on PC2) ports is working fine.

I am new to networking. Please let me know what could be possibly going wrong or any directions(tools/logs etc..) on how to go about solving this problem will be very helpful.

**Output of ifconfig :**

```
enp2s0 -> PCIe installed ethernet card
enp3s0 -> Default ethernet port

$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:36:9f:53:c3:f4  
          inet addr:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 240f:7c:7cd0:1:f80:54cc:44b4:3bb3/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 240f:7c:7cd0:1:dcba:8b05:591b:595b/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::7afd:cf24:4867:d06e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10234 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7945 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9581459 (9.5 MB)  TX bytes:1103246 (1.1 MB)
          Memory:f7900000-f79fffff 

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:54:37:e6  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:142306 (142.3 KB)  TX bytes:142306 (142.3 KB)
```

**Ethernet Card Information :**

```
$ lspci | awk '/net/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet I210-T1 GbE NIC
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Realtek one is fine. The problem I explained is with Intel I210 Network card.

Could the problem be possibly related to the default device drivers in ubuntu 16.04?

Kindly let me know if more information is required.